# Как правильно сохранить данные с чекбокса?

Tags: yii2

Доброй ночи всем.

view

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
....
echo Html::checkbox('category[]', false, ['value' => $childs['id'], 
'label'=> $childs['title']]) . '<br>';
....
$form = ActiveForm::end();
```

var_dump

```
[
'_csrf' => 'ZTROVV8ta1IneQstDV4/ZhxWLDg0axoNVmI.Ni1sWQUQRQpmL14aPQ=='
'category' => [
    0 => '262'
    1 => '264'
    2 => '265'
]
]
```

262, 264, 265 - это id категории. Помогите как правильно сохранить!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Если максимальное количество категорий известно, то можно добавить
   столько же полей в таблицу - плохой вариант, но быстро обрабатывать
   можно.
2. Собрать айдишники категорий в массив и записать в одно поле
   через запятую - так себе вариант, потому что накладывает ограничения
   потенциальных возможностей.
3. Создать дополнительную таблицу, куда
   записывать айди сущности и айди категории - немного сложнее
   обрабатывать, но появляется возможность получить некоторую
   статистику по количеству категорий для сущности (все сущности у
   которых менее 2 категорий, все сущности с более 5 категориями,
   сущности без категорий, популярные категории, популярные категории
   для конкретной сущности и т.д.)

Третий вариант более приемлем, потому что неизвестно как далее будут развиваться события.
Поля: id, entity_id, cat_id